# How can I set the space between elements of a set?

Tags: typography

I want to list all elements of a set. I tried

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[\left \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\right \}\]

\[\left \{0,\, 1, \,2, \, 3, \,4, \,5, \,6\right \}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there anyway that I do better?

Comment: What is wrong with `\[ \{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 \} \]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest trick by me.

```
\documentclass[border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\def\set[#1,#2]{$\{#1\foreach \x in {#2}{,\,\x}\}$}

\begin{document}
\set[1,2,3] and \set[1,] and an empty set \set[,]
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Version 2

Removing `$` to let you use other math environment.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\def\set[#1,#2]{\{#1\foreach \x in {#2}{,\,\x}\}}

\begin{document}
\[
    \set[1,2,3]
\]
 and $\set[1,]$ and an empty set $\set[,]$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ Money Oriented Progra How can I put this code `\[\set[1,2,3,\ldots, 100]\]` in mathmode?

Answer (score 4):

A “classical” definition, where the comma is math active and defined to give a comma followed by a thin space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\listset}[1]{\lbrace}{\rbrace}{%
  \begingroup
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`, \lowercase{\endgroup
    \def~}{\mathchar\commacode\,}%
  \mathcode`,=\string"8000
  #1
  \endgroup
}
\AtBeginDocument{\edef\commacode{\the\mathcode`,}}

\begin{document}

\[\listset{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}\]

\[\{0,\, 1, \,2, \, 3, \,4, \,5, \,6\}\]

\[\listset[\big]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}\]

\end{document}
```

Look in the documentation of `mathtools` what optional is accepted to a declared paired delimiter.

[image]

The same without activating the comma, but using `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,xparse}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\listset}[1]{\lbrace}{\rbrace}{\listsetaux{#1}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\listsetaux}{m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_minthao_listset_seq { , } { #1 }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_minthao_listset_seq { ,\, }
 }
\seq_new:N \l_minthao_listset_seq
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[\listset{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}\]

\[\{0,\, 1, \,2, \, 3, \,4, \,5, \,6\}\]

\[\listset[\big]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

A slight improvement on @Money Oriented Programmer's answer:

1. does not need workarounds for singleton and empty sets
2. uses `count` key of `pgffor` so you'll need a recent version. An alternative is using an `\iffirstelem` custom conditional
3. you can use notation like `\set{1,...,50}` or `\set{a,...,g}` which can be handy (see the pfg/tikz manual "Utilities > Repeating things")
4. use of `\ensuremath` to allow use outside and inside of mathmode
5. avoid using `[]` delimiters since the argument is not optional and `{}` brackets are more suggestive of an actual set

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[border=12pt,12pt,convert=png]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\def\set#1{%
    \ensuremath{%
        \ifx!#1!\emptyset\else
            \{%
                \foreach[count=\i] \x in {#1}{%
                    \ifnum\i>1,\,\fi%
                    \x%
                }%
            \}
        \fi%
    }%
}

\begin{document}
\set{1,...,3} and \set{1} and an empty set \set{}
\end{document}
```

[image: preview]

You may also be interested in the [braket](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/braket) package.

Comment: @ Rordaigorl I can not use `\[\set{1,...,15}\]`.

Comment: @minthao_2011 that is probably just because you cannot use `\[\]` with the `standalone` class. Use it with a standard class such as `article` and you will be fine

Answer (score 2):

To someone with a hammer, everything looks like a nail.

Thus, I too have my little hammer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xinttools}
\newcommand{\InsertExtraAfterCommas}[2][\,]
     {\xintListWithSep{,#1}{\xintCSVtoList {#2}}}

\begin{document}
\[\left \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\right \}\]

\[\left \{\InsertExtraAfterCommas{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}\right\}\]

\[\left \{\InsertExtraAfterCommas[\;\;\;]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}\right\}\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: extra spaces]